# Вызов ивента с задержкой. Как сделать?

Tags: разработка-игр, lua, roblox

У меня есть скрипт для того, чтоб когда я касался куба у него отнималось ХП

```
local cube = workspace.Cube
local HP = cube.Healthbar

local function Healtbar() do
    HP.Value = HP.Value - 5
end

cube.Touched:Connect(Healthbar)
```

Но ХП отнимается слишком быстро, буквально каждый фрейм когда я сталкиваюсь с кубом, а я хотел бы, чтоб после получения урона происходила небольшая пауза, после чего урон снова проходил, но простое wait() - не работает.